# Facebook Comments Plugin - Allowing user with session to delete comments

Tags: facebook, comments, facebook-social-plugins

I'm not sure if this is possible but I'll just ask. I'm using the FB comments plugin on my site, I know there are admin privileges as to be able to let admins moderate the comments, what I would like is for a way to allow the user to delete comments, like if the user was on FB he can delete comments made on his posts. Is this possible?

Comment: let me know https://www.facebook.com/insights help you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are no settings for this. Users can only delete their own posts. You would have to contact Facebook directly to request this.